# Error deploying node js restify application to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, dtrace, restify

I'm having an issue deploying a restify application to Heroku.

```
npm ERR! dtrace-provider@0.0.9 install: `node-waf clean ; node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-waf clean ; node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the dtrace-provider@0.0.9 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the dtrace-provider package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

It seems as if Heroku has an issue with dtrace, which restify makes use of, although doesn't require, I've read that you can bypass this by removing dtrace from restify's package.json file, however I have attempted this with no success.

I'm new to node and using Heroku and git so I'm sure there's something I'm missing, restify's package.json file contains the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "dtrace-provider": "0.0.9",
},
"optionalDependencies": {
    "dtrace-provider": "0.0.9"
},
```

I have removed these lines but still receive the same error message as above after committing to git and pushing to Heroku.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy your application on heroku it installs the dependencies based on your application package.json file so it does not matter if you remove it from restify's package.json file because heroku picks the restify's package.json file from it's repository not from your repository. So, you need to find out how to resolve this error.